# IdentityServer4 CORS issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, cors, identityserver4

We've set up CORS for our .NET 5 Web API that uses IdentityServer4 as authentication provider.

HTTP calls from our JS client (Ionic/Capacitor) to for example /account/register are working without a problem, but when we make a call to one of our "custom" API methods we get the following error message.

```
2021-02-19 10:38:10.092 +00:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /connect/userinfo from origin: http://192.168.1.152:8100
2021-02-19 10:38:10.099 +00:00 [DBG] Client list checked and origin: http://192.168.1.152:8100 is allowed
2021-02-19 10:38:10.101 +00:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://192.168.1.152:8100
2021-02-19 10:38:10.179 +00:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /api/schedule from origin: http://192.168.1.152:8100 but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint
```

We googled for this issue but the only we seem to find is how to configure CORS for IDS4 or .NET 5. We have our CORS set up like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://192.168.1.152:8100", "capacitor://localhost", "https://localhost:5001")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
    });

    // ...

    services.AddIdentityServer();

    // ...
}
```

After that we also tried setting the AllowedCorsOrigins property on the appropriate client like this. But no luck.

```
AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
{
    "http://192.168.1.152:8100", 
    "capacitor://localhost"
}
```

Configure setup is done like this, we tried switching UseCors() and UseIdentityServer() but this didn't help.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IMapper mapper)
{
    mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseCors();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

We also tried the "Adding more API Endpoints" entry in the IDS4 documentation, but this only seems to be meant for authorizing requests to those endpoints, which we already have set up ourselves.

Anyone has a clue what's going on?

Comment: You have to show all startup code, since Cors code should be placed in a special order.

Comment: @Sergey AddCors() is the first statement of ConfigureServices. UseCors() is called before UseIdentityServer().

Comment: Can you show Configure section at least . There are lots of rules there.

Comment: @Sergey there ain't much but I added it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a named policy instead of the default one. Sometimes it works better:

```
  services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigins", builder =>
            {
              builder.WithOrigins("http://192.168.1.152:8100", "capacitor://localhost", "https://localhost:5001")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

......
......

app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigins");
```

Comment: Not really sure why my answer was deleted, it contained the full fix. But I'll post it here again.. after adding a named policy and adding the origins to the AllowedCorsOrigins property, it was fixed. Thanks.